# Did any of the contestants on Masterchef not get a callback after the tasting but get on the show?

Tags: casting, masterchef

Just curious I’ve been reading all sorts of mixed things where some of the people that auditioned say they didn’t get called after the tasting to “learn more about the few contestants” and are still waiting to get on the show?

I was just curious if the casting of Masterchef actually chooses people that they didn’t originally pull aside after the tastings or not, or if it’s just between those people?